# Export configuration data along DLL when building

Tags: .net, dll, configurationmanager

I'm deploying a .NET application library DLLs with Visual Studio / msbuild. This library has many configurations for the multiple platforms it targets. I need to find a way to export some of the configuration data along each build, because the container that loads these DLL's has to be able to know which suits each platform.

I tried using custom assembly attributes, but these [require the assemblies to be loaded, which I can't do (even with `ReflectionOnlyLoad`)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10439668/getting-custom-assembly-attributes-without-loading-into-current-appdomain): I need to analyze each assembly *before* loading it, specifically to determine *whether it should be loaded at all*.

One solution would be to create a companion "meta" file to the DLL, who's content would be generated depending on preprocessor directives, for example:

`Configuration.txt`:

```
#if AOT
    AotCompile
#endif

#if NETFX_CORE
    DotNetCore
#endif

#if NO_THREADS
    NoThreads
#endif
```

After Googling I thought I could use [T4 Text Templates](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd820620.aspx), but it seems like they [cannot access compilation symbols](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4548794/t4-text-template-is-it-possible-to-get-compilation-symbols-from-host) (and the workaround suggested in that question cannot work in my build pipeline). There is [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27158674/154502) which offers a solution, but it involves manually editing each project file's XML, which is incredibly time consuming considering I have many projects.

Is there another way to export some or all of the configuration data when building?

Answer (score 0):

One simpler solution I found is to add this post-build event:

```
echo $(DefineConstants) > "$(TargetDir)\$(TargetName).defines"
```

Which outputs the defines, e.g. `TRACE;DEBUG` in a file name `MyProject.defines` alongside the DLL.

Comment: I'm not marking this as the answer yet, I'm curious to see if others can find a better approach.